# Custom search configuration in sitecore 7

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have been working on the sitecore contentSearch API recently.When i try to build the custom Index,I'm getting the runtime errors as follows.

```
Could not find property 'initializeOnAdd' on object of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration
```

This is my sample configuration.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="demo_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Sample</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
          <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
          <analyzer ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="_uniqueid"            storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="Name"  storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="imageurl">Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer.ComputedFields.ImageUrlComputedField,Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer</field>
            <field fieldName="releaseyear">Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer.ComputedFields.YearComputedField,Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer</field>
            </fields>
          <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <Laptop>{3AF80D80-404F-411F-9E72-F43A7D92AEC8}</Laptop>
          </include>
          <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders"/>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter"/>
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper"/>
        </LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I had a look at sitecore's search configuration file and do some changes on it.Type & analyzer settings.am i missing anything in configuration?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo somewhere. It should be `'InitializeOnAdd'` instead of `'InitialiOnAdd'`, but xml you pasted looks ok. Maybe in some other place in your configuration?

Comment: No this is the only configuration file which i have created for custom search.

Comment: Can you try <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by myself.here is the configuration setting for Sitecore 7 Custom search.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="demo_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Sample</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
           <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
          <analyzer ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="_uniqueid"            storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="imageurl">Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer.ComputedFields.ImageUrlComputedField,Lucene.CustomSearch.BusinessLayer</field>
            </fields>
          <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <Laptop>{3AF80D80-404F-411F-9E72-F43A7D92AEC8}</Laptop>
          </include>
          <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders"/>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter"/>
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper"/>
        </LuceneCustomSearchConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```